# How to change file name under ./mlrun when using MLflow

Tags: machine-learning, logging, artificial-intelligence, mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I am using mlflow to log parameters and metrics of my pytorch.lightning model.

```
class PD_Learner(pl.LightningModule):
    *mlflow is used here*
    ...
```

Before training, I log paramters using
`mlflow.log_params()`

My question is, when mlflow runs, it saves logs in such a way : mlruns/0/{some random name}

How can I change that {some random name} and also 0.

Any help is appreciated.

I tried using `mlflow.experiment(name='')` but that doesn't seem to change the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the names, MLFlow manages them to make your life easier. You have a user interface and API to enjoy the data with tags and ids assigned, not worrying about exact file paths.

But you may want to [change the file location of the backend store](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#backend-stores) with the flag
`--backend-store-uri` when starting a server. For instance, `--backend-store-uri /mflow-data`.